# Why parameter whose tokens are being iterated through should be ended with a non-empty macro, and what should that macro actually contain?

Tags: macros, expansion

I've asked this question more than once here, but all I could get is that "it's safer" to use a non-empty macro. I was never told why, and (more importantly) it was never clarified what exactly the macro should contain.

This code sample is a "looping" macro that iterates trough each token of its parameter:

```
\def\zEnd{\zEnd}
\def\zzIterator#1{%
    \ifx#1\zEnd
    \else
      #1%
      \expandafter\zzIterator
    \fi
  }
\def\zIterator#1{\zzIterator#1\zEnd}
\zIterator{hello}
```

There are 2 questions:

1. why `\def\zEnd{\zEnd}` should not be empty (should not be `\def\zEnd{}`)?
2. does it really matter what exact macro is inside the curly braces of `\zEnd`, whether the enclosed macro is itself `\zEnd` or anything else (like `\zIterator`, `\zzIterator`, or whatnot)?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The reason for using a 'quark' (a macro defined to expand to itself) is that it can never match *anything else*. If you use

```latex
\def\zEnd{}
```

then your marker is `\ifx` equal to `\empty`, so something like

```
\zIterator{hello\empty more tokens}
```

will stop early. It's the same with any other definition other than the marker itself: you need to be sure that the token is not in the input. Using a quark, we only have one 'restricted' token.

Answer (score 4):

> This code sample is a "looping" macro that iterates trough each token
>   of its parameter:
>
> ```
> \def\zEnd{\zEnd}
> \def\zzIterator#1{%
>     \ifx#1\zEnd
>     \else
>       #1%
>       \expandafter\zzIterator
>     \fi
>   }
> \def\zIterator#1{\zzIterator#1\zEnd}
> \zIterator{hello}
> ```
>
> There are 2 questions:
>
> 1. why `\def\zEnd{\zEnd}` should not be empty (should not be `\def\zEnd{}`)?
> 2. does it really matter what exact macro is inside the curly braces of `\zEnd`, whether the enclosed macro is itself `\zEnd` or anything else (like `\zIterator`, `\zzIterator`, or whatnot)?

The token `\zEnd` is used as "sentinel token" for ending iteration/recursion.

Ad 1: The `\ifx`-comparison triggers termination of the loop by comparing meanings of tokens.  In practise there won't be many tokens besides `\zEnd` which are defined to expand to `\zEnd`. But there may be many short macros that at some stage (temporarily) are defined to not deliver any token at all. Such macro-tokens would erroneously terminate the loop if `\zend` was defined as `\def\zEnd{}`.

Ad 2: It doesn't matter. What does matter is that the sentinel-token is choosen/defined in a way where it can be taken for granted/ensured that tokens of equal meaning do not occur within the argument/within the set of tokens that is to be iterated.

By the way: The statement "iterates trough each token of its parameter" is wrong:

The underlying looping macro `\zzIterator` does not process a single token but does proces a non-delimited argument. Therefore the looping macro does not iterate through each token of its parameter but iterates its parameter non-delimited-argument-wise until either encountering a non-delimited argument which has two leading tokens of equal meaning or encountering a token whose meaning equals the meaning of `\zEnd`.

"Non-delimited-argument-wise" implies the removal of one level of curly braces if present and the discarding of explicit space-tokens.

See, e.g., what happens with:

```
\def\zEnd{\zEnd}
\def\zzIterator#1{%
    \ifx#1\zEnd
       Iteration ends.
    \else
      Iteration processes: #1 %
      \expandafter\zzIterator
    \fi
  }
\def\zIterator#1{\zzIterator#1\zEnd}
\def\gobble#1{}%
\let\foobar=\zEnd

\zIterator{hel\foobar lo\gobble}
\bigskip

\zIterator{h{ell}o}
\bigskip

\zIterator{ {h} {ell} {o} }
\bigskip

\zIterator{he{ll\gobble}o\gobble}
\bigskip

% Don't do:
%\zIterator{he{ll}o}
% Here \ifx will compare l to l and then \zEnd will be carried out, 
% yielding a never terminating recursion as \zEnd calls itself again
% and again...
\bye
```

Reversing the tokens to be compared by `\ifx` is a bit safer as you won't get into
the `\zIterator{he{ll}o}`-pitfall:

```
\def\zEnd{\zEnd}
\def\zzIterator#1{%
    \ifx\zEnd#1%<---- reversed.
    \else
      #1%
      \expandafter\zzIterator
    \fi
}
\def\zIterator#1{\zzIterator#1\zEnd}
\zIterator{hello}
```

The loop can still be outmanoeuvred by tokens equal to `\zEnd` and by (unbalanced) `\if..`/`\else`/`\fi` in the argument.

Detecting emptiness of arguments is a bit safer:

```
\long\def\firstoftwo#1#2{#1}
\long\def\secondoftwo#1#2{#2}
%%=============================================================================
%% Check whether argument is empty:
%%=============================================================================
%% \CheckWhetherNull{<Argument which is to be checked>}%
%%                  {<Tokens to be delivered in case that argument
%%                    which is to be checked is empty>}%
%%                  {<Tokens to be delivered in case that argument
%%                    which is to be checked is not empty>}%
%%
%% Due to \romannumeral0-expansion the result is delivered after two
%% expansion-steps/after two "hits" by \expandafter.
%%
%% The gist of this macro comes from Robert R. Schneck's \ifempty-macro:
%% <https://groups.google.com/forum/#!original/comp.text.tex/kuOEIQIrElc/lUg37FmhA74J>
%%
\long\def\CheckWhetherNull#1{%
  \romannumeral0\expandafter\secondoftwo\string{\expandafter
  \secondoftwo\expandafter{\expandafter{\string#1}\expandafter
  \secondoftwo\string}\expandafter\firstoftwo\expandafter{\expandafter
  \secondoftwo\string}\firstoftwo\expandafter{} \secondoftwo}%
  {\firstoftwo\expandafter{} \firstoftwo}%
}%
%%=============================================================================
\long\def\IIterator#1#2{%
  \expandafter\CheckWhetherNull\expandafter{\firstoftwo{}#1}{%
     Iteration terminated.%
  }{%
    Processing: #2 %
    \expandafter\IIterator\expandafter{\firstoftwo{}#1}%
  }%
}%
\long\def\Iterator#1{\IIterator{#1{}}#1{}}%
%%
\Iterator{hello}%
\bigskip\par
\Iterator{he{ll}o}%
\bigskip\par    
Of course this does---like the other variants---not take space-tokens
into account because \firstoftwo{\TeX}{} discards space-tokens that
precede non-delimited arguments:
\bigskip\par
\Iterator{ h e l l o }%

\bye
```